# Bidirectional OneToMany vs OneToOne association with mappedBy attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I defined entities with **@OneToOne** bidirectional relationship.

Owner site of relationship (***Child*** class):

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
private Parent parent;
```

Other site (***Parent*** class):

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
private Child child;
```

When I try to persist Parent who has child set (which is not persisted) then I got exception

- TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

which looks understandable.

But when I defined entities with bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne association like:

The owning site of this relationship:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
private Parent parent;
```

The other side of the relationship:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<Child> childrens = new HashSet<>();
```

and try to persist Parent who has children collection set (which are not persisted) then I can do it and Hibernate persist only Parent.

For me it looks strange because this behavior is not deterministic - I know that this example is not correctly and I can use *CascadeType.ALL* or persist it correctly.
Do you know why it looks that ?
Is that Hibernate use different algorithms to persist entities in @OneToOne/@OneToMany relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `cascade = PERSIST` on the `@OneToMany` you should see the same error. The difference is just that Hibernate does not try to "manage" *-to-many associations on the inverse side i.e. where the `mappedBy` is present.